# When I use Scapy to analyze some UDP packets, and generate a list, when I read a list value, it display garbled

Tags: python, udp, wireshark, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *
import re

def get_seq(data):
    list1 = []
    try:
        recive = rdpcap(r"/home/luokai/sipp/pcap/" + data)
        for r in recive:
            a = r[Raw].load
            list1.append(a)

    p = list1[0]
    print p
except:
    print "Error"
```

result:

�~~��~~�~������~~~}~~~~�������~~~~��~��~}~~�~�~~�~�~~~}}}}~����������������~�}~~~�������~�~~�~~~�~���~���~~~�~��~�~��������}�~��~~~~����

Answer (score 0):

You display binary data as a string. You should just replace `print p` by `print repr(p)`, for example, for something more readable.

Comment: OK after replace repr , it display right , but three has some error when i read data, it miss some string

Comment: Then this answers your question. You should accept this answer and ask another question: stackoverflow works with basic (atomic) questions, so one answer may help other people with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing Raw Binary Data you could convert it to a str by doing:

```
s=str(packet)
print s
```

but that is probably not what you want so you should do:

```
packet.show()
```